# Calling custom code in an inherited interface?

Tags: c++, interface

How would I call custom code external to the classes, but from within the concrete object? E.g. If I wanted to change the state of an object or variable that is external to the class? Functors? Callbacks?

Would I need to store the functor or callback in the interface or in the ADT?...assuming using a functor or callback is what I'm supposed to do...

## **EDIT**

After fighting with Functors and templates definitions all day I fell back to using function pointers. Now all the user does is register a previously defined function name and it gets called. Since the member variable defaults to `nullptr` if they don't register one, nothing happens but the default behavior. See edited code below.

Button Interface:

```
class IButton {

public:
    virtual void OnPress() = 0;
    virtual void OnRelease() = 0;
    virtual void OnHover() = 0;
protected:
private:

};
```

Button ADT:

```
#include "IButton.h"
//..More includes

class ADTButton : public IButton {

public:

    //..Other methods...

    virtual void OnRelease()=0;
    virtual void OnPress()=0;
    virtual void OnHover()=0;
    
    virtual void OnRelease(ADTButton* btn);
    virtual void OnPress(ADTButton* btn);
    virtual void OnHover(ADTButton* btn);

    virtual void RegisterOnReleaseCallback(void (*OnReleaseCallBack)(ADTButton* btn));
    virtual void RegisterOnPressCallback(void (*OnPressCallBack)(ADTButton* btn));
    virtual void RegisterOnHoverCallback(void (*OnHoverCallBack)(ADTButton* btn));

protected:
    
    void (*_OnRelease)(ADTButton* btn);
    void (*_OnPress)(ADTButton* btn);
    void (*_OnHover)(ADTButton* btn);


    //..More Stuff Here in various access modifiers

};
```

Concrete Button header:

```
class CpuButton : public ADTButton {
public:

    CpuButton();
    virtual ~CpuButton();

    virtual void OnRelease();
    virtual void OnPress();
    virtual void OnHover();

protected:
private:
};
```

Concrete Button Implementation:

```
#include "BTN_CPU.h"
    
void CpuButton::OnRelease() {
    ADTButton::OnRelease();
    if(this->_OnRelease) this->_OnRelease(this);
}

void CpuButton::OnPress() {
    ADTButton::OnPress();
    if(this->_OnPress) this->_OnPress(this);
}

void CpuButton::OnHover() {
    ADTButton::OnHover();
    if(this->_OnHover) this->_OnHover(this);
}
```

Comment: I don't find the question very clear... what do you mean by custom code? What exactly stops you from writing the code directly in `//..Custom code called here`?

Comment: @Yaniv Any code that is not inside the class or passed in as a variable. The point is that I want to keep the interface as-is but want to have different behavior for different concrete classes when the methods are called.

Comment: @Casey - you are basically describing `virtual` functions.. so its not clear what you want to do different. Can you provide a more specific example? If you want to access variables outside the class you need a way to do that, perhaps store it in `CpuButton` but beyond that, not sure where you are stuck.

Comment: You could provide a method that accepts and stores functions that should be called back when an event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

You can have another interface that provides various behaviour based on its own concrete implementation and call methods of this interface via a pointer to a concrete implementation stored as a member variable. This is callback of course. You can also use policy templates to do this in compile time.